# can someone rectify this add , a background on java and change it with stat pressed left or right

Tags: java, android, background, pressed

hy everybody , i need a help traying to add a background on android slider.java , so i want to have a background and to change it like this :

```
getBackground ( R.drawable_slider_bg);
if leftslider = PRESSED (getBackground = (R.drawable.slider_left_bg));
if rightslider = PRESSED (getBackground = (R.drawable.slider_right_bg));
```

can someone help pleas ?

Edit : what about this , any sugestion ?

```
public void setBackgroundDrawable (int) {
    setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.slider_bg);
    if (LeftSlider == STATE_PRESSED) {
    setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable_slider_bg_left);
   }
        if (RightSlider == STATE_PRESSED) {
    setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable_slider_bg_right);
   }
};
```

cheers

Comment: Please don't post huge chunks of code. It's hard for us to go through. Being succinct will increase your chances for getting an answer.

Comment: hi edited now , as i have no java developpement experience , i need to make that ive descripted can you help pleas ?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to change the background image of the slider based on the direction that it's moving in?

Comment: yes exactly , i want to have a background and on the background we have a rectangle and the sliders are in it , when i put the left slider the background changes but with the same igage i have moded to show cursor , and same for the right , on layout is imple to do it , bu my lense lockscreens background has affected too